# An escrow account in my web marketpalce

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal

I want to build a marketplace in my website.

I want to supervise all the transactions in this marketPalce,

thus I want the buyer to put his money in my escrow account

before paying the seller.

I though to use paypal.

What do i need to include in my UI?

My website's paypal userName?

Any serial # ?

Comment: Escrow is a complicated system with many legal implications for you and your end users. Have you considered just focusing on your marketplace product instead and using a 3rd party service for escrow?

Comment: did you find any solution...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Government Regulated Escrow Websites like www.Transpact.com allow easy integration (just one line of .aspx code or php code), and have all the functionality you need built in.
As MisterJames says, Escrow is complicated with many legal implications, so it is much easier and more advisable (and much cheaper) to use an existing Government Regulated website.